# Changing the default iOS dictionary from New Oxford American Dictionary(NOAD) to Oxford English Dictionary(OED)?

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

Anywhere in  the iPhone when you select a word the Define option pops up from the popup menu. Clicking on it brings up the definition for that word. The default dictionary it uses is the New Oxford American Dictionary(NOAD). I wonder if it can be changed to the Oxford English Dictionary(OED).

[image]

Image source: osxdaily.com

Comment: Do you already have the language and keyboard set to British or uk English?

Comment: @Tom: Sure did. Doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: try typing "colour" in notes and then select and define

Comment: @TomGewecke Defines it. But uses the NOAD. Did the same thing on my Mac, and the result was different under the OED.

Comment: works for me, I don't know what to suggest -- tried a reset?

Comment: @TomGewecke: Reset? Not really. I don't remember the password to that part. Can you post a screenshot of your dictionary definition for the word **grammar**? I am interested in getting to know whether a particular noun is a mass noun or not. The OED has it, while the NOAD doesn't.

Comment: To reset iPad, press and hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button at the same time for at least 10 seconds, until the Apple logo appears.  My definition has mass noun as the first entry.

Comment: @TomGewecke I am using iPhone. Do you think that will make any difference?

Comment: no, ios should be same on all devices

Comment: @TomGewecke Didnt work. Just tried it.

Comment: I don't understand why some users cannot get all the dictionaries.  Normally using the right keyboard to type something and doing define should force a download of dictionaries for UK English, French, German, Spanish, Chinese, Japanese.

Comment: @Tom: that's what I think it should do. Do you think it can be resolved?

Comment: Until someone comes up with a fix, I don't know how.

Comment: It is ODE, not OED. -basically the same content as NOAD, just with British English. No extra info.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is possible in iOS 7. When you click to define a word, in the bottom left there is a "Manage" button. Here, you can tap the X for a dictionary that you want to delete from your device and tap the cloud button to download a dictionary you want. So in your case, tap the X to delete the NOAD from your iPhone, and tap the cloud to download the OED to your iPhone.

Comment: That's true....

Comment: In iOS 9, there is no longer an X button to remove a dictionary; instead swipe left on the entry.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible currently as applications implement a dictionary priority stack. That is, more specifically, unless the application specifies a dictionary, the top most dictionary from the "English"-dictionaries stack is used. As Apple-apps do not provide a selection interface for the dictionary priority, the NOAD is used.

Comment: How does your assertion square with the fact that on a properly working ipad like mine, you can get the OED instead of the NOAD on Apple apps by switching to the English (UK) keyboard and asking "Define" for a word spelled in the British manner?  Same for German, French, Spanish, Japanese, and Chinese, with appropriate words and keyboard switches?

Comment: That was not an assertion. Changing the keyboard does change the systems' priority stack on dictionaries.

Comment: Then your "answer" makes no sense, because it should be possible for the OP to get his OED by default by changing his keyboard. (Unfortunately it does not work on his device).

Comment: Could you please step back with your arrogance and try to understand me as a developer. The dictionary is selected from a priority stack, that stack depends on the users locale and keyboard settings. However, every application implements different selection algorithms. I, for myself, can't use the OED as default dictionary, too. This does also apply to my iPad Mini, iPad (4th gen) and iPhone (5th gen). That is, either you have a magic iOS device or please explain what you do to enable the dictionary. Try to get rid of it and re-enable it. How did you do that? Tell us! :)

Comment: I think @TomGewecke is right. If you can get dictionaries for French and other languages how come you cannot get the OED for BrE? If i am able to get French or Spanish dics, I should also be able to get the OED. Not sure where the problem lies, though.

Comment: Are you not able to use the OED (or get it downloaded if you have never used it before), by typing a British English word in Notes with the English UK keyboard and selecting it and doing Define?  That is how it is supposed to work, and that is how it works for me, no magic involved.  Or are you saying you can indeed get the OED for Notes and iBooks, etc but not for every app? I don't know of any way to remove any of the reference dictionaries once you have them in iOS.

Comment: Okay, here's my guess: if you have used the NOAD and added words yourself, it'll be preferred. I can't think of any alternative.

Comment: You can't add words to the reference dictionaries, only spellcheck which is a totally different dictionary system.  Please tell us whether you yourself have the OED available or not.

Comment: As I said before, no.